# How to convert 4 byte IEEE (little endian) float binary representation to float

Tags: python, c, floating-point, binary, ieee-754

I am decoding a binary file, which has decimal numbers represented by four bytes, little endian. For example, `94 53 F0 40` represents 7.510202. Unfortunately, Python is giving me 7.51020240784.

When I try to parse this data using `unpack("<f",sampledata)[0]` I don't get exact representations of the original, due to the way Python stores values (for more information, see http://bugs.python.org/issue4114).

Unfortunately, I *do* need to get the *exact* same representation- regardless of discussions about the inaccuray of floats, because I need to write these values to a text file, with the same number of decimal places as they were initially written to the binary file with.

I'd rather stick to Python if possible, but am happy to implement a solution in C if necessary. The reason I cannot simply truncate the return of the unpack function, is that I cannot guarantee how many decimal places the original float had, for example `0C 02 0F 41` represents 8.938 according to my hex editor, from the original binary file, which only has 3 decimal places.

To be clear, I need to take four hex bytes as my input, and output either a text/ASCII or number representation of the IEEE 32-bit floating point number, that has the same number of decimal places as was intended by the creator of the file. The output I will use to create a CSV of the original binary data file, not for actually performing any calculations.

Any suggestions?

Example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from struct import *

print("Should print 7.510202")

hexbytes = b"\x94\x53\xF0\x40"

# 01101001 11001000 11110001 01000000
# should print 7.510202

print(unpack("<f",hexbytes)[0])
```

Comment: No, `94 53 F0 40` does *not* represent `7.510202`; that value isn't exactly representable in either single- or double-precision IEEE 754 binary floating-point.  It represents the number `7.5102024078369140625` (exactly).  If you need more information from the original text file (like the number of decimal places originally used to describe the number), you're going to have to track that information separately.  By the time you pass to just a single-precision float, that information is gone.

Comment: Well, both the correctly decoded file, AND my hex editor give me 7.510202. I don't care how they got there, but I wish to do the same. See http://imgur.com/Tmx3bD9

Comment: Then your hex editor is probably just giving an output based on 7 significant digits.  To get the same result in Python, do `"%.7g" % x`.

Comment: You are burying your head in the sand. That number is not representable in a binary floating point type. Futile to pretend otherwise. There is no bug afflicting you. Everything is behaving as designed. If you want to round to 6dp, do so.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan rounding to an arbitrary number of decimal places isn't as trivial as it seems. There's a `round` function but it only works if you already know how many decimals to the right are required, and for arbitrary input that can change drastically.

Comment: I had already tried truncating/rounding but as Mark says, basic rounding just wasn't giving me the right output, when compared to the officially decoded sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 4-byte IEEE format floating point number holds approximately 7 digits. What you want to do is round the result of `unpack` to a total of 7 digits. From there the normal Python conversion from float to string will hide all the floating point nastiness from you.

```
def magnitude(x):
    return 0 if x==0 else int(math.floor(math.log10(abs(x)))) + 1

def round_total_digits(x, digits=7):
    return round(x, digits - magnitude(x))

>>> round_total_digits(struct.unpack('<f', '\x94\x53\xF0\x40')[0])
7.510202
>>> round_total_digits(struct.unpack('<f', '\x0C\x02\x0F\x41')[0])
8.938
>>> x = struct.unpack('<f', struct.pack('<f', 12345.67))[0]
>>> x
12345.669921875
>>> round_total_digits(x)
12345.67
```

Note that if your numbers did not originate from a direct conversion of a decimal number but were the result of a calculation, this could *reduce* the total accuracy. But not by much.

Comment: Mark, thank you so much. I need to read this a couple of times to really get my head around why it works, but it does so perfectly- my results are now exactly as they should be. Thanks again. I couldn't work out the magnitude part of the rounding.

Comment: @Chris what I call `magnitude` is really just the number of digits to the left of the decimal point, or negative the number of leading zeros on the right. And it's off by 1 for numbers less than 1.0 so I'll make an edit.

Comment: I don't think much of this. As a general rule, one stores the value as is, and just formats when printing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ordinarily I would agree with you, but in this case the OP *insists* that the numbers started with a limited number of decimal digits. This process is simply restoring the bits that were lost through the conversion to 32 bits. Note my caveat at the end. And certainly there's nothing stopping you from storing the values as-is and simply using this function at print time.

Comment: I don't think the asker understands binary floating point. This answer helps them continue that way in my view. I've said my peace.

Comment: Ultimately, I'm trying to match some known output, character for character, which Marks answer works perfectly for. I'm not quite sure whether my understanding of binary floating point numbers is important here. Have I missed something!?

Comment: A simpler and more robust approach is to use string formatting: `def round_total_digits(x, digits=7): return float("{:.{}e}".format(x, digits))`.  That avoids potential issues from inaccuracies in the `log10` call.

Comment: Whoops; off by one there.  The returned value should be `float("{:.{}e}".format(x, digits-1))`

Comment: Mark D,  two questions, one, in what circumstances might the accepted answer not work? And two, does this work out the correct number of decimal places to round to? (7 is sometimes to many, as per the original question).

Comment: @Chris: Mark Ransom's approach is probably fine in practice; I'm just a stickler for corner cases.  The problematic cases are infinities, nans, and values *very* close to powers of 10.0.  For example, on my machine, `magnitude` returns `24` for an input of `1e23`, where it should technically return `23` instead (because the actual value stored for `1e23` is just slightly less than `10**23`).  To your second question: no, it doesn't magically guess how many decimal places were in the originally-read float.  It can't: that information simply doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 1):

```
  uint32_t b = 0x40F05394 + printf("");

  printf("%.11f\n", *(float *) &b);
```

prints in my (little endian) system:

```
7.51020240784
```

so you need to print more digits with `f` conversion specifier. Same with python you can just request the number of digits to be printed.

Example:

```
print "%.11f" % (unpack("<f",hexbytes)[0])
```

If the number of digits to be printed is variable in your text file, you have to also store this information in your text file.

Then in C you can print it:

```
      int p = 11;
      printf("%.*f\n", p, *(float *) &b);  // 11 here can be a variable
```

In Python:

```
     p = 11
     print "%.*f" % (p, (unpack("<f",hexbytes)[0]))  # 11 can be a variable
```

Of course to have `0x40F05394` from `0x9453F040`, you just need to re-arrange the order of the bytes.

Comment: Thanks ouah, But how do I get it without the 40784? I can get it with the extra garbage, but I want it without.

Comment: @Chris did you try to use 6 instead of 11 in my examples?

Comment: ouah, I would have given it a go, but with Mark's Python answer coming up, I didn't get round to it (I'm not great in C, frankly).

Comment: @Chris this is fine, my answer intentionally silently misses the issue of rounding and maybe I should have addressed this first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to encode and decode in little endian. This doesn't address any rounding issues, but looks like those were worked out in the answer above.

```
import csv, os
import struct

test_floats = [1.2, 0.377, 4.001, 5, -3.4]

## write test floats to a new csv file:
path_test_csv = os.path.abspath('data-test/test.csv')
print path_test_csv
test_csv = open(path_test_csv, 'w')
wr = csv.writer(test_csv)
for x in test_floats:
    wr.writerow([x])
test_csv.close()


## write test floats as binary
path_test_binary = os.path.abspath('data-test/test.binary')
test_binary = open(path_test_binary, 'w')
for x in test_floats:
    binary_data = struct.pack('<f', x)
    test_binary.write(binary_data)
test_binary.close()


## read in test binary
binary = open(path_test_binary, 'rb')
binary.seek(0,2) ## seeks to the end of the file (needed for getting number of bytes)
num_bytes = binary.tell() ## how many bytes are in this file is stored as num_bytes
# print num_bytes
binary.seek(0) ## seeks back to beginning of file
i = 0 ## index of bytes we are on
while i < num_bytes:
    binary_data = binary.read(4) ## reads in 4 bytes = 8 hex characters = 32-bits
    i += 4 ## we seeked ahead 4 bytes by reading them, so now increment index i
    unpacked = struct.unpack("<f", binary_data) ## <f denotes little endian float encoding
    print tuple(unpacked)[0]
```